# Swift Encode Custom String to populate URL

Tags: ios, swift, string, url, encoding

I have a `URL` that takes any `String` like this:

```
https://test@api.search?query=\(productSearchString)&limit=1
```

Now my problem is that this works with for example "iphone" but it crashes with "iphone 12".
I tried encoding it like this:

```
guard let escapedResourceString = resourceString.addingPercentEncoding(withAllowedCharacters: .urlHostAllowed) else { return  }
```

but this doesn't seem to work in my case because it is returning an incorrect `URL` that I can not use with my API.

How can I fix this, so the user can type in anything he want but the `URL` should be created and my API should be able to work with it.

If you need anything more just let me know.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your parameters needs to be url encoded.

You can use [URLComponents](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/foundation/urlcomponents) to create your `URL` and pass your parameters as `URLQueryItem` instances, like that:

```
let productSearchString = "iphone 12"
var urlComponents = URLComponents(string: "https://test@api.search")
urlComponents?.queryItems = [
    URLQueryItem(name: "query", value: productSearchString),
    URLQueryItem(name: "limit", value: "1")
]
let url = urlComponents?.url

print(url?.absoluteString ?? "nil") // https://test@api.search?query=iphone%2012&limit=1
```

Comment: i updated my question, in my case the `String` is not actually at the end but in the middle. Is your answer still working for this? And what exactly is your code doing?

Comment: `limit=1` was just an example, in reality there can be anything behind that, even more paramters depends on the situation in my case :D sorry if I didn't make that clear..

Comment: is there not a simple way to `encode` my  searchString and simply populate my actual `URL` with it?

Comment: @Chris `URLComponents` can be used to create a url from separate components, in your case from a string that is valid and some query parameters that needs to be url encoded.

Comment: @Chris to compose the url yourself you need to run multiple times `addingPercentEncoding(withAllowedCharacters:)` function passing `.urlQueryAllowed` as allowed characters set for each parameter value. I think `URLComponents` is far easier.

Comment: @Chris to pass more parameters modify the code to create more `URLQueryItem` instances and pass them in the `queryItems` property.